# when does $\limsup(a_n + b_n) < \limsup(a_n) + \limsup(b_n)$ holds?

Tags: real-analysis

I proved the inequality for $\limsup(a_n + b_n) \le \limsup(a_n) + \limsup(b_n)$

but when is the strict inequality true given as  $\limsup(a_n + b_n) < \limsup(a_n)+ \limsup(b_n)$

for me, i think it may be true that if $\limsup(a_n) + \limsup(b_n)$ both diverge individually, but the $a_n +b_n$ sequences converge, then this strict inequality holds.  but is this the only case?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

$\limsup a_n$ and $\limsup b_n$ don't have to be infinite - it is sufficient that $a_n$ is small when $b_n$ is big and conversely.

One simple example is

$a_n = (-1)^n \\ 
b_n = -(-1)^n$

with

$\limsup a_n = \limsup b_n = 1$ and $\limsup( a_n+b_n ) = 0.$

Comment: You could give any example with $b_n = -a_n$ and $\limsup a_n \ne 0 \ne \limsup b_n$ (+1)